# Dismiss new UIWindow does not trigger viewWillAppear in base window

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In my current project, I have a `RootViewcontroller` presenting a `navigation controller` containing a `HolidayViewController`.
This `HolidayViewController` calls a function that create a NEW window so that the user can login into a different service.
After the login is successful, the NEW window is dismissed with the following code (from the NEW window rootViewController):

NOTE: `base` being `HolidayViewController.view.window`

```
rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
   if self.isKeyWindow || base.isKeyWindow {
      base.makeKeyAndVisible()
   }
   windowLevel = UIWindow.Level(-1)
})
```

Everything looks fine except that `HolidayViewController` `viewWillAppear` is not called when the NEW window is dismissed.
I could use `NotificationCenter` or a `completion` block to force an action but I don't want to do this as I would like my NEW window to be more generic and actually use the normal iOS events chain.

Is it normal? Is there a way to make it work nicely?

Answer (score 0):

if NEW window is presented as modal, then dismissing NEW window will not call viewwillappear of HolidayViewController. Because HolidayViewController is already in view hierarchy and visible under NEW window. You can use delegation to call methods of HolidayViewController while dismissing your NEW window.

Comment: I'm thinking of a solution to observe window.isKeyWindow but so far it doesn't trigger.

Comment: from my point of view. Observing the key window may not be a good idea, it may be triggered by other places too when even you don't want.